# syntax for adding line to query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have just changed a script to use

```
$query=$database->query (INSERT...)
```

but I also have several if statements that add to the query if the number of input fields generated from the previous page is higher than expected.

The original query is as follows...

```
$query=$database->query("INSERT INTO pool_" . $pool_name . " (team_name) VALUES('$team_one'),     ('$team_two'), ('$team_three'), ('$team_four'), ('$team_five'),
('$team_six'), ('$team_seven'), ('$team_eight')");
```

I understand the error I am getting, I just don't know how to avoid it.

> The error is Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could
>   not be converted to string in
>   D:\newXamp\htdocs\real_do_create_pool.php on line 32

the line of code is...

```
$query.=", ('$team_nine'), ('$team_ten'), ('$team_eleven')";
```

How can I add to the query whilst using $database->query

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be VALUES('$team_one', '$team_two', '$team_three') and so on?

Comment: well when i was using mysql_query, mysql_result etc, the deprecated methods, I just added to $query like I have shown above, however, since changing to $query=$database->query, it won't work. I could type them all in again but hoped there was a shortcut

Comment: Wait, I took a stab at the answer, but now I'm not sure; what is your table structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call $database->query until it's all baked:

```
$queryString = "INSERT INTO pool_" . $pool_name . " (team_name) VALUES('$team_one'),     ('$team_two'), ('$team_three'), ('$team_four'), ('$team_five'),
('$team_six'), ('$team_seven'), ('$team_eight')";
```

Then as necessary you can:

```
$queryString .=", ('$team_nine'), ('$team_ten'), ('$team_eleven')";
```

and then finally

```
$query=$database->query($queryString);
```

Edit: Or even better, use the magic that is [PDO prepared statements](http://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements)

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO pool_" . $pool_name . " (team_name) VALUES (:team_name)");
$stmt->bindParam(':team_name', $team_name);
$stmt->execute();
```

Got some more to insert?

```
$team_name = $team_nine;
$stmt->execute();
$team_name = $team_ten;
$stmt->execute();
```

etc

Comment: Now with bonus PDO option!

Comment: Just want to mention, that you should always use prepared statements when dealing with user input.  Otherwise you might have SQL Injection on your hands.